# Background a task then end connection before task completion in Java (8)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8

I've spent a lot of time looking at this and there are a tonne of ways to background in Java (I'm specifically looking at Java 8 solutions, it should be noted).

Ok, so here is my (generic) situation - please note this is an example, so don't spend time over the way it works/what it's doing:

- Someone requests something via an API call
- The API retrieves some data from a datastore
- However, I want to cache this aggregated response in some caching system
- I need to call a cache API (via REST) to cache this response
- I do not want to wait until this call is done before returning the response to the original API call

Some vague code structure:

```
@GET
@ // api definitions
public Response myAPIMethod(){
    // get data from datastore
    Object o = getData();

    // submit request to cache data, without blocking
    saveDataToCache();

    // return the response to the Client
    return Response.ok(data).build();
}
```

What is the "best" (optimal, safest, standard) way to run `saveDataToCache` in the background without having to wait before returning `data`? Note that this caching should not occur too often (maybe a couple of times a second).

I attempted this a couple of ways, specifically with CompletableFutures but when I put in some logging it seemed that it always waited before returning the response (I did not call `get`).

Basically the connection from the client might close, before that caching call has finished - but I want it to have finished :) I'm not sure if the rules are the same as this is during the lifetime of a client connection.

Thanks in advance for any advice, let me know if anything is unclear... I tried to define it in a way understandable to those without the domain knowledge of what I'm trying to do (which I cannot disclose).

Comment: What does "I attempted this a couple of ways, specifically  with Futures" mean? Does that mean you used an ExecutorService and submitted a Runnable or Callable?

Comment: @BrettOkken I used `CompletableFuture` along with `runAsync` and `supplyAsync` (but the info I worked from was rather vague).

Comment: Question, to fully understand your use case... So you *always* go to the datastore and then want to asynchronously put the result in a cache. Is this OK? You **don't** want to use the cache to retrieve a cached value, right?

Comment: @Magnamag yeah, in the above completely ignore the fact that you can get back the cached version - my only concern is how to persist to that cache (you can assume `getData`  does all that stuff)

Comment: @Zack OK, understood that. So tell us a little bit more about those calls to the cache API via REST. Are you using a client provided by the cache implementors? Or are you just using an HTTP client, like Apache HttpComponents HttpClient, to send the actual requests?

Comment: @Magnamag an official client, which returns a Future (although under the hood it's probably just a HttpClient, because the client works over HTTP).

Comment: @Magnamag (which makes me wonder if I can just ignore that Future, and it's already taken care of? but regardless, the question still stands because I want to know for future references)

Comment: @Zack The Future is returned to you as a handle by this official client. If you don't take care of it, no one will. If this official client is *really* asynchronous, then you could do just nothing, but in case of any error, you'd loose the chance to take any action upon it, such as retrying, saving the info to a log, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, the cache API is already asynchronous (it actually returns a `Future`). I suppose it creates and manages an internal `ExecutorService` or receives one at startup.

My point is that there's no need to take care of the objects to cache, but of the *returned `Future`s.* Asynchronous behavior is actually provided by the cache client.

One option would be to just ignore the `Future` returned by this client. The problem with this approach is that you loose the chance to take a corrective action in case an error occurrs when attempting to store the object in the cache. In fact, you would never know that something went wrong.

Another option would be to take care of the returned `Future`. One way is with a `Queue`, as suggested in another answer, though I'd use a [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) instead, since it's unbounded *and you have mentioned that adding objects to the cache would happen as much as twice a second*. You could `offer()` the `Future` to the queue as soon as the cache client returns it and then, in another thread, that would be running an infinite loop, you could `poll()` the queue for a `Future` and, if a non null value is returned, invoke `isDone()` on it. (If the queue returns null it means it's empty, so you might want to sleep for a few milliseconds).

If `isDone()` returns `true`, you can safely invoke `get()` on the future, surrounded by a `try/catch` block that catches any `ExecutionException` and handles it as you wish. (You could retry the operation on the cache, log what happened, etc).

If `isDone()` returns `false`, you could simply `offer()` the `Future` to the queue again.

Now, here we're talking about handling errors from asynchronous operations *of a cache*. I wouldn't do anything and let the future returned by the cache client go in peace. If something goes wrong, the worst thing that may happen is that you'd have to go to the datastore again to retrieve the object.

Comment: This is the type of detail I was looking for - specifically the fact that you detailed the thing I mentioned in the comments about just ignoring the `Future` (which is good for my actual use case). Am I correct in thinking that getting back a `Future` is essentially a guarantee that the method will be doing its thing in the background? Will returning and closing the client connection mess with that in any way?

Thank you for the detail surrounding `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` (and linking it back to my use case). The walk through was very helpful.

Comment: @zackehh Getting back a `Future` only guarantees that the action it represents has been submitted to an executor. This action could be running in the background, could have been canceled or might have finished, either successfully or with an exception. Regarding returning and closing the client connection, it won't affect the background action, since they will be running on different threads.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider [adding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#add-E-) the objects to cache into a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and have a separate thread [taking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take--) from the queue and storing into cache.

Comment: Interesting, never looked at BlockingQueue before. Is this an optimal way to do this (appears to be quite raw)? E.g. is this better than something like `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @Zackehh9lives what do "optimal" and "raw" mean to you? The ThreadPoolExecutor uses a BlockingQueue to manage tasks. So these are well used structures.

Comment: Optimal above meaning the most performant. And I'm weary as I have never come across them when looking for solutions.

Comment: It performs quite well. You will need to test in your workflow specifically to see if it works for your specific case.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives It is only slightly different than using an `ExecutorService`. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` is the most likely `ExecutorService` that you would use. It is backed by a `BlockingQueue`. When you submit a task, it is added to the queue. Waiting threads pull from the queue. My proposal is similar to using a single thread executor with the only real difference being that in the case of failure, it is easy to add the item back to the queue to try again in future.

Comment: Using a queue is helpful since it decouples the request handling from whoever (i.e., what executor service or whatever) is doing the cache storage. Note that it's possible to use a `BlockingQueue` in non-blocking mode by using `offer()` instead of `put()`. This is important if the web requests come in faster than items can be stored in the cache. It allows web requests to avoid being throttled to the cache storage rate, at the cost of dropping cache storage requests.